# Rename a property of the model to map the return data of a procedure in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I am using code first approach to call many precedures from `Sql Server` database but I have a small issue relating to model mapping. I created a model like below:

```
public class UserVesselPermissionsResult
{
    public Guid VesselId { get; set; }
    public int PositionType { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public int PermissionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public Guid CrewPositionId { get; set; }
}
```

After that I call a procedure like below:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<UserVesselPermissionsResult>("exec dbo.UserVesselPermissions @UserGUID, @Date",
            new SqlParameter("UserGUID", userId), 
            new SqlParameter("Date", date == default(DateTime) ? DateTime.Now : date));
```

which returns me the result from database. The procedure is like below:

```
Select  cp.[VesselGUID], 
            cp.PositionType, 
            cp.Department, 
            ISNULL(p.PermissionID,0) [PermissionID], 
            ISNULL(c.FName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(c.SName,'') [Name], 
            cpt.Name [Position], 
            cp.CrewPositionGUID

    FROM...
```

I tried with debug mode and as far as I can see it fetches the data only for properties with the same name as in the `select` statement in procedure, but the properties `VesselId` and `PermissionId` have the default values, which means there is a problem in naming convention I think...

Is that possible to map `VesselId` -> `VesselGUID` and `PermissionId` -> `PermissionID` without changing the procedure because it is being used in other systems as well, so I can not change the select statement in any way.

I tried putting `[Column("VesselGUID")]` but it did not work...

Is there any attribute like `[ProcedureColumnName("VesselGUID")]` to map these properties ?

Hope this is not duplicate but I searched about two hours and did not find the proper solution about that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing procedure select query by giving an alias to each field:

```
Select  cp.[VesselGUID] as VesselId, 
        cp.PositionType, 
        cp.Department, 
        ISNULL(p.PermissionID,0) as PermissionId, 
        ISNULL(c.FName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(c.SName,'') [Name], 
        cpt.Name [Position], 
        cp.CrewPositionGUID as CrewPositionId

FROM...
```

So, now it works goood :)